# Plesk Obsidian NodeJS for React give me error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, plesk

I could not find the document on how to install react application to Plesk panel on the internet.

Based on some documents I found, I uploaded the unpublished version of the application in /httpdocs.

```
Node.js Version : 12.18.0  
Document root /httpdocs    
Application mode production  

Application root /httpdocs [open]
Application start file src/index.tsx  [edit]
```

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

```
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
```

You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stderr is shown below:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\blablabla.com\httpdocs\src\index.tsx:1
import React from "react";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:210:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
```

Comment: Here follow this tutorial https://muthu322.medium.com/react-express-developement-production-on-plesk-1fe4db0ca312